# Ruby Code to verify AAD token in correct

Tags: ruby, azure, token

I have a scenario of calling Rubi API which is AAD authenticated

I have the code to generate AAD token from Client ID and Secret.

But need to code to verify the token is correct or not when it reaches the Ruby API.

Answer (score 4):

AAD token is usually JWT, so you can use any JWT library, like: https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt

There is also an omniauth - AAD provider: https://github.com/AzureAD/omniauth-azure-activedirectory